# Prove a generalization of a convergence test

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_{n})^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a positive sequence of real numbers, such that $lim_{N→∞} (sup_{n≥N}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{ a_{n}})$ exists and
equals $l$, forsome $l ∈[0,1)$. Prove that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_{n}$
converges.

It is a generalization of one of the convergence test, and a full proof is required for this question.

Could someone show the steps of the proof? Thanks!

Comment: step 1, fix $p$ with $l<p<1$ and fix a large enough $N$ such that $\sup_{n≥N} \frac{a_{n+1}}{ a_{n}}<p$

Comment: @Mirko Sorry I am not able to follow this hint yet...  So could you give an answer?

Comment: think a bit more, if $n>N$ then $a_n< p^{n-N} a_N$

Answer (score 1):

The essence of this proof is to compare your series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n$ with a geometric series that you know that converges. For that you will need to build such sequence. Also note that if you have a given series that has a finite number of ridiculously big numbers, but then starting from some order $N$ it is a well-behaved, converging series, then the series as a whole converges.

What I mean is: Let $M$ be some *really big* number and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. If $b_i$ is defined as:

- $M$ if $i \le N$
- $c_{i-N}$ if $i > N$

Then $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} b_i = \sum_{i=0}^{N} M + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_i = M\cdot N + \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} c_n$ and therefore $b_n$ converges if and only if $c_n$ converges, right? Take a moment to let that sink in.

Because of that, it suffices to show that if your sequence complies to your test, then it is below *some* geometric series $g_n$ of ratio $r$ with $|r| < 1$ starting with some order $N$. That is, apart from some $N$ initial terms that need not be below $g_n$, the terms $a_i, i > N$ satisfy $a_i < g_i$. Because $g_n$ has ratio $|r| < 1$ then $g_n$ converges and what is more,

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_n = \sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i + \sum_{i=(N+1)}^{\infty} a_i \le \sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i + \sum_{i=(N+1)}^{\infty} g_i = \sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i + g_N\frac{1}{1-r}$$

Notice now that $\sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i$ is a regular sum with a **finite** number of terms. Therefore your series $a_n$ converges. You are left with proving that you can construct such a series $g_n$ with a relative ease.